# Trigger en Oracle para una sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql, trigger

Estoy intentando crear un trigger para que a la hora de insertar un registro, me dispare un campo autoincrementable

```
CREATE TABLE customer(
 id_customer NUMBER(3) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 nombre VARCHAR2(50)
)


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auto_increment BEFORE INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

BEGIN

    SELECT SEQUENCE_CUSTOMER.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id_customer FROM DUAL;

END;
/
```

El ERROR: not enough values

Comment: Yo no uso Oracle, pero hasta donde se ya tiene una sintaxis predeterminada para crear `sequences` mira aquí [fuente oficial](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm) al final del documento viene un ejemplo

Comment: Si la secuencia se como crearla, pero mi pregunta es hacer un trigger para que cada vez que se  haga un insert, se dispare el trigger de autoincrementar, y me llene automaticamente el campo id_customer

Comment: El error que comentas podría venir de la sentencia `insert()`, pero no veo de donde en el código del trigger que publicas.

Answer (score 1):

He reproducido tu ejemplo y creo que sé dónde está el error.

He creado la secuencia del siguiente modo:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE CUSTOMERSQ INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 MAXVALUE 10000 MINVALUE 1;
```

He lanzado tres insert diferentes siguiendo tu modelo.

```sql
insert into customer(nombre) values('nombre1');
```

```
1 fila insertadas.
```

En este caso me inserta la fila sin problema con el id_customer a 1

```sql
insert into customer values ( 7,'nombre2');
```

```
1 fila insertadas.
```

En este caso me inserta la fila sin problema con el id_customer a 2 pese a que yo le he dicho que tenga id_customer 7

```sql
insert into customer values ( 'nombre2');
```

```
Error SQL: ORA-00947: no hay suficientes valores
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"
```

En este último caso, que creo que es el tuyo da error. Es lógico, porque en SQL si no especificas los campos al hacer un insert presupone que le vas a pasar todos los datos y espera que le pases 2, sin embargo sólo le estás pasando uno.

Aunque luego el trigger le ponga el valor que tú quieras es un problema de gramática de SQL no de programación del trigger